# Spring MVC Annotated Controller not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've got a really annoying issue... I've not defined a Controller handler mapper and therefore I'm using the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` class. My issue seems to have something to do with the Controller bean name mapping to the Controller class e.g.

Incoming request to dispatcher -> index.htm

With the following Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController { 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginForm(ModelMap model) {
        return "index";
    }  
}
```

Should map index.htm to indexController bean and then to IndexController class. I can see from the logs that Spring has registered the bean with the container however I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [xxx.controller.IndexController]
```

I know for certain that the class exists (because the bean name is derived from it).

The strange thing is that if I name my controller the same as the bean name (e.g. indexController) everything is fine!! (Obviously I don't want my classes to have a lower case first letter!!)

Just to note that I've used the following in my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx" />
```

JLove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually means your class has not been bundled in the war file. Unzip the war file and check your class is included correctly.

I suspect you successfully bundled "indexController.class" at some point, but prior packaging attempts failed. You haven't indicated how you are packaging your application, check your Maven/Ant configuration if you are using one of those. Beware of sharing build directories between IDE and build script, as they can occasionally conflict with each other.

Comment: Thanks... I believe that the issue was to do with the hot deployment used by Netbeans. Because I've only changed the case of the class name I think it did not believe the file had changed. I cleaned my project and re-deployed and all is fine!!

Answer (score -1):

I'd advice you to download [STS](http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts) and create new Spring MVC project template, to see, how Spring 3 MVC works.

Comment: I understand the principles used with Spring MVC... I'm asking for specific help.